# push notification react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Подскажите как лучше реализовать уведомления (Notifications) в react-native.

PS. Использую react-native-create-app

Answer (score 2):

Для push notifications можно использовать кросс-платформенный сервис [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM). Для Android это "родной" сервис, а для iOS он пересылает уведомления в APNS. Есть [open-source библиотека](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) для использования FCM в React Native. С интеграцией данной библиотеки в приложение вам поможет [эта статья (en)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/push-notification-for-react-native-bef05ea4d1d0).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/push-notifications.html

Подходящий вариант использовать expo.io, представленный выше способ использует схему: каждому приложению присваивается токен (с помощью 
 Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()), далее с ним делается POST запрос на сервер expo (https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send) - и приходит нотис на устройство. В статье выше так же рассматривается способ с участием вашего сервера где будет храниться база с токенами